# changing button text and replacing span

Tags: jquery, button, click

I have a button that I want to change the text on it once clicked. Annoyingly I did have it working with this code yesterday, but it now seems to be broken.

(edit) ***I now know i was missing the jQuery library***

I'm also looking to show the `span` with '+' sign when 'add to friends list' is being shown and hide / not show when just 'added' is being shown:

Here's my basic jQuery:

```
$("#addTo").click(function() {
   $(this).text("Added");
});
```

HTML

```
<button type="submit" id="addTo"><span>+</span>Add to Friends List</button>
```

Fiddle here too:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ue3Zb/

Thanks. Y.

Comment: It works fine, i think you forgot to select jQuery as the library

Comment: Haha *sadface*, but for the second part?

Comment: You are missing jQuery reference http://jsfiddle.net/Ue3Zb/3/

Comment: @badZoke so the it show's the + `span` when on "add to friends list" and not when 'added' is shown, but when clicked again it goes back to showing 'add to friends list' with the '+' showing etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**here is the Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ue3Zb/7/)

code is here  -

```
$("#addTo").click(function() {
  if($(this).text()=="Added"){
    $(this).html("<span>+</span>Add to Friends List");
  }
  else 
    $(this).text("Added");
});
```

what you were missing to check what is the current status for the button and accordingly you need to put the html inside button

that means if the text is `Added` then we need to put this `<span>+</span>Add to Friends List` html inside the button and if the text is not `Added` we need to make it `Added`

*Note: You also forgot to add jQuery library there*

Comment: The SO does NOT want the `+` to be shown, to quote, "hide / not show when just 'added' is being shown:"

Comment: okay.. you question was bit confusing for me first with the comment in yours regarding second part i got it :) waiting for @badZoke to remove the downvote

Comment: @RohitAgrawal if you calm down abit, yes.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add jQuery reference..

```
<button type="submit" id="addTo"><span>+</span>Add to Friends List</button>
```

[**SEE Updated FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ue3Zb/2/)

Comment: could have been a comment instead.